# tee stdout to stderr?

Tags: io-redirection, stdout, stdin, tee

I'd like to send stdout from one process to the stdin of another process, but also to the console. Sending stdout to stdout+stderr, for instance.

For example, I've got `git edit` aliased to the following:

```
git status --short | cut -b4- | xargs gvim --remote
```

I'd like the list of filenames to be sent to the screen as well as to `xargs`.

So, is there a `tee`-like utility that'll do this? So that I can do something like:

```
git status --short | \
    cut -b4- | almost-but-not-quite-entirely-unlike-tee | \
    xargs gvim --remote
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`tee` can duplicate to the current console by using `tee /dev/tty`

```
git status --short | cut -b4- | tee /dev/tty | xargs gvim --remote
```

<del>Alteratively, you can use `/dev/stdout`or `/dev/stderr` but they could be redirected if your command is within a script. Note that `/dev/tty` will always be the console (and may not exist in a non-interactive shell).</del> This is wrong, read the comments.

Comment: Indeed, in the pipeline you show `/dev/stdout` *is* redirected. That is, if you were using `tee /dev/stdout` the effect would be that everything is sent to `xargs` twice, and nothing goes to the terminal.

Comment: `/dev/stdout` is not redirected by a pipe, it will stay the current process standard output. However, if you encapsulate the command in a script and then redirect the stdout of this script, then `/dev/stdout` will be redirected. In an interactive console, `tee /dev/tty` and `tee /dev/stdout` has the same effect, even when using pipes.

Comment: If you don't believe me, start your shell and type `echo foo | tee /dev/stdout | tr f b` and `echo foo | tee /dev/tty | tr f b`. Here's a hint for you: It is `tee` which interprets the `/dev/stdout` as file name.

Comment: You are right, I do not know how I missed that. I did some tests in my own shell with tty and stdout and I do somehow missed that. Thanks for the clarification, I removed the wrong statement.

Comment: Well, given that stderr is not affected by the pipe, you would not have needed to remove that (of course the script redirection caveat remains, but for a script, redirectability would generally be a desired property).

Answer (score 8):

A more general solution than `/dev/tty`:

```
start cmd:> echo foo | tee /dev/stderr 
foo
foo
```

Comment: `start cmd:> ` is your `$PS1`?

Comment: @mgalgs Part of my `PS1`, yes: http://www.hauke-laging.de/software/prompt/ (German)

Comment: Using `/dev/stderr` does not work if you have `su`ed into another user... but `/dev/tty` does

Answer (score 3):

You can use **tee** command, just feed it with STDERR file, as example:

```
tee /dev/stderr
tee /proc/self/fd/2
```

so in that case your alias maybe:

```
git status --short | \
    cut -b4- | tee /dev/stderr | \
    xargs gvim --remote
```

Comment: I think you mean `/proc/self/fd/2`